# Bootstrap 4 column to dictate height of another column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a pure CSS way for one column in bootstrap grid to 'dictate' the height of another within the same row? So if for example I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-sm-6" id="column1">
    <!-- an object the height of which will be different based on screen width -->
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-6" id="column2">
    <!-- another object, also with varying height - might be bigger or smaller than the first object -->
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need is for the column with id "column1" to force the second column width id "column2" to have the same width. 
The purpose is to have a picture of varying size in the first column and description text in second column. The description text might take bigger height than the picture due to its length but it must not increase the height of the column and instead hide the overflow text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by wrapping the contents of the right column into another div that is absolutely positioned, and have the parent `.col` have the `overflow-y: scroll;` property on it, like in the example below.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-sm-6" id="column1">
            <!-- an object the height of which will be different based on screen width -->
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200?text=Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-6" id="column2" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
            <!-- another object, also with varying height - might be bigger or smaller than the first object -->
            <div class="position-absolute">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur egestas dapibus nisi eget pretium. Morbi neque risus, bibendum porttitor eleifend non, iaculis vitae est. Proin fermentum nisi ut urna aliquet, maximus laoreet ante maximus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum dignissim metus vel dui consectetur, at bibendum enim interdum. Duis feugiat ipsum ut varius lobortis. Suspendisse id justo sapien. Phasellus bibendum lacus aliquet velit aliquam commodo. Praesent pellentesque dui vel gravida lobortis. Nam ullamcorper pellentesque viverra. Vestibulum tortor odio, pretium vel accumsan ut, rutrum vitae neque. Sed congue a risus sed dapibus. Quisque eu sem tincidunt, facilisis odio vitae, efficitur odio. Curabitur tortor nulla, volutpat ut leo et, egestas dignissim mi. 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

`.position-absolute` is a Bootstrap [Positioning utility](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#common-values) class that sets `position: absolute;` on the element.